# Do skill check re-rolls include dice gained from spending clue tokens?

Tags: arkham-horror

If I have 2 rolls for my skill check, and I fail the roll, then I spend a clue token to roll, and I fail. I then spend a second clue and again fail.

If I now use the Lucky Cigarette Case  which says:

> Discard Lucky Cigarette Case to re-roll any one skill check.

Do I roll the original 2 dice only, or have I increased my re-roll pool to 4 dice (by including the additional dice from spending 2 clues)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reroll all 4 dice.

It's important to do things in the right order though.  Using the cigarette case and then clues results in fewer total rolls.

This is clarified in the FAQ contained within the [Dunwich Horror rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/DH_rules_english.pdf)

> **Q:** How does a re-roll work? Can you re-roll only the
>   skill dice that you have before spending Clue tokens, or
>   can you re-roll all the dice you’ve rolled on a given
>   check, including the extra dice gained from spending
>   Clue tokens?
>
> **A:** You re-roll all the dice you’ve rolled for the skill
>   check so far, so you can re-roll dice gained from spending
>   Clue tokens as long as you spend your Clue tokens
>   before using your re-roll.